# $lookup is not working after adding limit and skip in aggregate function

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, limit, lookup, skip

I am new in mongodb and i confused why my lookup is not working in my below scenario

// lookup is not working

```
[
   {
      "$match":{
         "is_active":{
            "$eq":1
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$facet":{
         "length":[
            {
               "$count":"total"
            }
         ],
         "data":[
            {
               "$skip":0
            },
            {
               "$limit":10
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"offences",
         "localField":"offences",
         "foreignField":"offence_id",
         "as":"offenceSetail"
      }
   },
   {
      "$project":{
         "offences.is_active":0
      }
   },
   {
      "$replaceRoot":{
         "newRoot":{
            "$mergeObjects":[
               {
                  "$arrayElemAt":[
                     "$offenceSetail",
                     0
                  ]
               },
               "$$ROOT"
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$project":{
         "offenceSetail":0
      }
   },
   {
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"registers",
         "localField":"user_id",
         "foreignField":"id",
         "as":"sender"
      }
   },
   {
      "$project":{
         "registers.is_active":0
      }
   },
   {
      "$replaceRoot":{
         "newRoot":{
            "$mergeObjects":[
               {
                  "$arrayElemAt":[
                     "$sender",
                     0
                  ]
               },
               "$$ROOT"
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$project":{
         "sender":0
      }
   }
],
"options":{

}
}
```

//lookup is working

```
[
   {
      "$match":{
         "is_active":{
            "$eq":1
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"offences",
         "localField":"offences",
         "foreignField":"offence_id",
         "as":"offenceSetail"
      }
   },
   {
      "$project":{
         "offences.is_active":0
      }
   },
   {
      "$replaceRoot":{
         "newRoot":{
            "$mergeObjects":[
               {
                  "$arrayElemAt":[
                     "$offenceSetail",
                     0
                  ]
               },
               "$$ROOT"
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$project":{
         "offenceSetail":0
      }
   },
   {
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"registers",
         "localField":"user_id",
         "foreignField":"id",
         "as":"sender"
      }
   },
   {
      "$project":{
         "registers.is_active":0
      }
   },
   {
      "$replaceRoot":{
         "newRoot":{
            "$mergeObjects":[
               {
                  "$arrayElemAt":[
                     "$sender",
                     0
                  ]
               },
               "$$ROOT"
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$project":{
         "sender":0
      }
   },
   {
      "$facet":{
         "length":[
            {
               "$count":"total"
            }
         ],
         "data":[
            {
               "$skip":0
            },
            {
               "$limit":10
            }
         ]
      }
   }
],
"options":{

}
}
```

Please help me how can I resolve it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The lookup in the first case is not working because the local field specified in the lookup is not present. After the `$facet` stage, we get two arrays i.e. `length` and `data`. We need to specify the `localField` as `data.offences`.

Answer (score 0):

Using $facet you will be able to run two aggregate at the same time. Each field you get using $facet represents separate aggregation pipeline and that's why you always get an array as output.

```
{
  "$facet":{
     "length":[
        {
           "$count":"total"
        }
     ],
     "data":[
        { "$skip":0 },
        { "$limit":10 }
     ]
  }
```

}

You will get two arrays i.e. length and data. Example:

```
{
"length" : [ 
    {
        "total" : 360
    }
],
"data" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d5beae5662cdb57e2b80eff"),
        "is_active": 1
    }, 
...
]
```

}

So you have to $unwind "data" first. Then do lookup operation. So you can do something like this

```
// After $facet
{
    $unwind: "$data"
},
{
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"offences",
         "localField":"data.offences",
         "foreignField":"offence_id",
         "as":"offenceSetail"
      }
 },
{
    $unwind: "$offenceSetail"
}
```

Comment: Hello Ashutosh, I did as you said, lookup is working but total count of record is not fetching however i am getting total count of limited records i.e 10